# firebase.auth(...).getUserByEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

In my project I need to link an existing email account whithout the user signed in.
I have the user's email, so I'm trying this code:

```
firebase.auth().getUserByEmail(useremail);
```

on the client side.
But it gives me the `firebase.auth(...).getUserByEmail is not a function error.`

Does anyone know how to get the user by email address on the client side so I can link the accounts, the existing one and the providers?

Thanks in advance.

Using sdk 17.4.5

Comment: I think the **getUserByEmail** method is only available for the Firebase Admin SDK. You might want to use some kind of server (or cloud function) so you could use the Firebase Admin SDK to fetch the user by E-mail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For web clients, `firebase.auth()` returns an [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) object.  As you can see from the API documentation, there is no getUserByEmail method. on it.  You're probably looking at the API documentation for [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth) from the Firebase Admin SDK, which does not work on web clients. It only works on backends running nodejs.

If you want to use `getUserByEmail`, you'll need to run it on a backend, and invoke that from your web client.

You should know that linking user accounts does actually require the use of this method. You [link accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) after the user has signed in to both of them.

Comment: I did that, invoke the getUserByEmail in the backend , but now i'm getting this error: TypeError: user.linkWithPopup is not a function . I do an ajax call to the backend, return the user record as json and then I do this  success: function (response) {
                    resolve(response.d);
                }

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.  Stack Overflow is meant for one issue at a time.  Note that you can't also invoke the client APIs on the server.